# OSMdroid how to add watermark

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm creating an free Android application and I'm using OpenStreetMap (OSMdroid library). I have a question. On the webpage: https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
I have read, that I should put a text in the corner of map activity (@OpenStreetMap contributors). 
How to do this?
I'd like my app to be comply with the OSM license.
Regards

Comment: I think having a big text like this in the bottom of the map view is a bit exaggerated.  Are you sure you can't simply add credits to them in the license section of your app?

Comment: I had to do this in About section but after reading this site I'm confused

Comment: @DoxPL, I think [spy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50968755/4118280) is exactly what you are looking for. Please consider accepting that answer. It will make it easier for other users to find the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have your layout file simply add a `TextView` with "@OpenStreetMap contributors" to it. (I recommend to use a `RelativeLayout`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="OpenStreetMap Contributors" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I saw in other apps that on startup they all show this and a few seconds later it is fading out so you can use a delayed animation for that.

```
textView.animate().setStartDelay(3000).alpha(0).setDuration(1000).start();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in copyright overlay for displaying the notice based on the current tile source.

Edit, sample code is below

```
//Copyright overlay
mCopyrightOverlay = new CopyrightOverlay(context);
mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mCopyrightOverlay);
```

Basically, whatever the current tile source is, the text overlay will be drawn.

Comment: will this overlay be displayed automatically or do I need to enable it in some way? If so, is there some sample code that shows how to do it?

Comment: @sky, great! Thank you.